# Invoke Java program present in EC2 using SNS notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke a java jar command on a EC2 instance. This has to happen when a SNS notification on new file addition to S3 is received. Can we do this without using a lambda?

Comment: If you are Ok to have REST end point hosted on EC2, this might work: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways

1. Install a web server on your EC2 instance and make sure it is a publicly accessible endpoint. Then you can set this endpoint as a subscriber to the SNS
2. If you want it to be more resilient (although  costing more) you can create a SQS, set this SQS as the subscriber to the SNS topic and then from within the EC2 instance poll the SQS. This way even when your EC2 instance is down for some reason the notification will not be lost

Comment: Thanks.. I will try this.